# Hide div element conditionally in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new ReactJS, there is a code where I am supposed to hide the below div until the data is returned from the backend. So there is an input where the ID is searched upon clicking the submit button. Once the info is retrieved, only then the

Name "XYZ"

Address "123,abc"

should be displayed.
As of now it diplays,( blank space in front of it) so I just want the Name and Address titles to be hidden until the data is retrieved.

Name

Address

Below is the code:

```
 <div className="info">
    <div className="info-block">
        <div className="info-title"><TranslatedString stringId="name" /></div>
        <div className="info-cell">{returnObj?.data?.name}</div>
        <div className="info-title"><TranslatedString stringId="address" /></div>
        <div className="info-cell">{returnObj?.data?.address}</div>                 
    </div>
 </div>
```

returnObj is where the data from the backend is stored. I tried adding condition on the info-title and info-cell like stringId={returnObj?.status == "Success"?"name":null} but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent rendering the div before the data has been fetched, you could do:

```
{returnObj?.data && (
    <div className="info">
      <div className="info-block">
        <div className="info-title"><TranslatedString stringId="name" /></div>
        <div className="info-cell">{returnObj.data.name}</div>
        <div className="info-title"><TranslatedString stringId="address" /></div>
        <div className="info-cell">{returnObj.data.address}</div>                 
      </div>
    </div>
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of the div can be controlled during fetch request by maintaing state.

```
const [isDivVisible, setIsDivVisible] = useState(false)
    const fetchReq=async()=>{
        setIsDivVisible(false)
        const res=await fetch(url)
        const data=await res.json()
        setIsDivVisible(true)
    }
```

before the fetch request starts make state false and after the result is fetched turn it to true and use to in inline styling of div

```
const styles={display:isDivVisible?block:none}
    return (
        <div style={styles}>
Your code
        </div>
```